# Disable touchpad tap to click in certain areas

Tags: linux, touchpad

My palms resting on my touchpad are being detected as taps, even though I have set `PalmDetect=1`.

I've experienced the same problem using `libinput` in the past, and am currently using `synaptics`, but would switch back to `libinput` if a solution can be found there.

I've also tried playing with various settings of `PalmMinWidth` and `PalmMinZ` but with no luck.

My palms generally rest on the left and right edges. I have seen settings such as `RBCornerButton` but there is no `RightEdgeButton`.

Is there a way to enable tap to click only for the centre of the trackpad where my wrists never touch?